# TypeError: format.match is not a function in moment angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, momentjs

Hi I am trying to compare today's date with ng-repeat date field using momentJS

here is my html code

```
<span class="time-stamp float-right" ng-if="recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' == todayDate">{{ recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'hh:mm A' }}</span>
        <span class="time-stamp float-right" ng-if="recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' != todayDate">{{ recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }}</span>
```

and here is today's variable I declared

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

if(day<10)
{
    day = '0' + day;
}
if(month<10)
{
  month = '0' + month;
}
$scope.todayDate = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
```

but when I compare it gives me error of TypeError: format.match is not a function any help please that how to compare with today's date

EDIT - {{ recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }} gives perfect result as 08/04/2016 like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the binding syntax is evaluating an expression: Add () to date/filter:
{{ (recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY') == todayDate }}

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried that
 like
<span class="time-stamp float-right" ng-if="{{recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' == todayDate}}">{{ recent.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'hh:mm A' }}</span>

Comment: is todayDate in your scope? It should work then. {{ todayDate }} works too?

Comment: Thanks buddy I forgot to remove {{ in ng-if condition it works now