# Jquery - Fullcalender - Moment Js Error - expandFormat

Tags: jquery, format, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am working on project that use **jquery fullcalendar** (v1) in which date format is like ...

```
var initial = $.fullCalendar.formatDate($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'), "MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Recently, we migrate full-calendar to v3, that use **moment.js**, code look like this ...

```
var initialdate = moment($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')).format("MM DD YYYY 00:00:00");
```

and i am getting following error on this line.

> moment.js:1177 Uncaught TypeError: expandFormat(...).match is not a function(…)

Comment: Can you share your page code? In this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/2x2ntt59/ it works correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: format.match is not a function in moment angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513967/typeerror-format-match-is-not-a-function-in-moment-angularjs)